Is there a list of known needed public-host-pattern for pnpm?
So, the default public-host-pattern for pnpm is [*eslint*, *prettier*], but I just discovered that I needed to add @types* as well, and I'm currently tracking down an aws issue that will likely result in another. Is there already a kind of database or list for known incompatibilities with node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules? It seems like a good idea and that it would be a widespread problem. I'd expect a similar list for pnp resolution like yarn berry

There is no such list. We would prefer tools to work correctly without the workarounds.
If you have issues you can use the node-linker=hoisted setting to create a “flat” node_modules similar to the one created by npm CLI.

I didn't mean from like the pnpm team, I meant from a ragtag group of underground mutants trying to survive in a cruel and unforgiving dystopian hellscape like the frontend ecosystem. This should be a common expectation in any kind of evolutionary transition. I think the Wine library has the gold starndard for such a database, but stuff like snaps and flatpaks also need such a database. Optimism and idealism just cause pain in my experience. Is there still a benefit to using pnpm over npm if I use node-linker=hoisted? Not rhetorical

There is an advantage as it will still use pnpm’s global store. So, less disk space usage. Also, there are some features that are not available in npm, like patched dependencies.
You could also just hoist everything with public-hoist-pattern[]=* instead. If that solves the issue.

Thanks, I just went with your initial suggestion and that works, I though it would make pnpm pointless, but sounds like I misunderstood how it all works. And excuse the sass, I'm not the original maintainer of this monorepo and every step of trying to align it with current best practices has been so so painful
